# Text to column vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to split a column if a certain header is used. So far when i run my code it finds the column, add the new column to the right, changes the headings but then throws an error for the text to column part. I used record macro and then changed it slightly.

```
Sub CUSIPSymbol()
Dim acell As Range
Dim CCUSIP As Integer

Set acell = Sheets("Fixed Income").Range("A1:Z4").Find(What:="CUSIP/ Symbol", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not acell Is Nothing Then
CCUSIP = acell.Column
Cells(1, CCUSIP + 1).EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(2, CCUSIP).Value = "CUSIP"
Cells(2, CCUSIP + 1).Value = "Symbol"
Columns(CCUSIP).TextToColumns Destination:=Range(Cells(1, CCUSIP)), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End If

End Sub
```

Getting the following error

`Method 'Range' of object'_Global failed`

Is there any issue in syntax?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: Method 'Range' of object'_Global failed

Comment: This isn't my area of expertise, but don't range expressions require two cell references?  The range you're specifying in the `TextToColumns` command has just one.

Comment: This link might help [Range Object _Global failed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601110/run-time-error-1004-method-range-of-object-global-failed).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub CUSIPSymbol()
Dim acell As Range
Dim CCUSIP As Integer

Set acell = Sheets("Fixed Income").Range("A1:Z4").Find(What:="CUSIP/ Symbol", LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
If Not acell Is Nothing Then
CCUSIP = acell.Column
Cells(1, CCUSIP + 1).EntireColumn.Insert , CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
Cells(2, CCUSIP).Value = "CUSIP"
Cells(2, CCUSIP + 1).Value = "Symbol"
Columns(CCUSIP).TextToColumns Destination:=Range(Cells(1, CCUSIP), Cells(100, CCUSIP)), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
    FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(9, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
End If

End Sub
```

As advised by Ann L. I added a second cell in the range reference. I added one well below what i expect to run into so it would be flexible.